# Problem with displaying image from file in PHP

Tags: php

I've been practicing PHP, and tried to work with images. I have and image called `avatar.png` inside `zdjeciaUzytkownikow` folder in my working directory, but when I try to display it by following PHP code

```
<?php
$image = "<img src='".getcwd()."/zdjeciaUzytkownikow/avatar.png'"." alt='brak avatara' width=200>";
echo $image;
?>
```

I launch my php application with XAMPP but no matter what I'm trying (changing the slashes, changing absolute path to relative, adding `_` at its beginning(so with path like: `_/zdjeciaUzytkownikow/avatar.png`)) i still get the alternate message, even though the following file is inside this folder... what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: urls use forward slashes

Comment: Well, changing slashes didn't help I already said I tried with both versions.(Though I change them to forward in question to not mislead anyone else)